# Is there a way to automatically show available options of React-Select

Tags: react-select

I have implemented React-Select like this

```
 {hints && hints.length ? (
    <Select
      value={pattern}
      isClearable={true}
      autoFocus={true}
      onChange={selectValue => {
        fetchImages(selectValue);
      }}
      options={hints}
    />
  ) : null}
```

That is inside return block of react functional component. As long as there are no hints/options the Select is hidden. However, when it gets options it is only single line with cursor. Is there an option that forces it to show options list automatically?

Comment: show your state in hints.

Comment: Hints come from props, no use of putting them to state. however soultion is found, the option I was looking for :menuIsOpen ={true}

Answer (score 0):

It was that simple:

```
menuIsOpen ={true}
```

sorry for bothering